# Trouble with label in TIKZ-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I cannot seem to figure out why the following won't work when I add a label. I will show the working example first, I want a simple commutative diagram with a label on each arrow. The working example is below:

`\begin{tikzcd}[matrix scale=2.5, transform shape, nodes={scale=1.5}]
%
M \arrow{rd}{\varphi} \arrow[r] &N\dar[dashed]{\,\exists!\Phi}\\
&L
\end{tikzcd}`

which gives:

[image]

But I would like to add iota on the arrow to N, which I tried here:

`\begin{tikzcd}[matrix scale=2.5, transform shape, nodes={scale=1.5}]
%
M \arrow{rd}{\varphi} \arrow[r]{\iota} &N\dar[dashed]{\,\exists!\Phi}\\
&L
\end{tikzcd}`

But I get a "Missing \endcsname inserted" and i cannot seem to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example, including preamble and document class. Also if you indents each line with 4 or more spaces the pasted source code looks a lot nicer

Comment: Ah, look at `\arrow[r]{\iota} ` notice a difference with the others? The braces! Double `{} ` not `[] {} `

Comment: @daleif You're a life saver. It's always some silly mistake. Thanks. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept if you like.

Comment: Either `\arrow{r}{\iota}` or the alternate input `\arrow[r,"\iota"]`. For the down arrow, it would be `\arrow[d,dashed,"\exists!\Phi"]`

Comment: @egreg I use overleaf and it doesn't seem to work with the multiple argument syntax, i.e. This error happened because I originally tried /arrow[d, "\varphi"] but it gives an error, so I used the old syntax. This seems to be a problem people have in general with overleaf.

Comment: @Jimmy2Goons Unfortunately, it seems that Overleaf lags quite behind the current TeX Live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple typo

```
\arrow{r}{\iota}
```

Not

```
\arrow[r]{\iota}
```